# Gmail API with PubSub PUSH notification, time issue

Tags: php, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I am developing a ticket system, where customer can ask their queries or questions about services, When customer send mail to SUPPORT email id, then an automatic mail will be sent to customer with an unique #TicketId,

For this scenario, I am using Gmail API with PubSub PUSH type notification, When I got notification by PubSub that a new mail is arrived, then from PHP by Gmail API I will send mail to customer with #TicketId,

Everything is working fine, but there are timing issue when I check mails on Gmail, it is showing time of sent mail earlier than receive mail, same I got in my db also,

I am using `internalDate` key of mail(message) for save datetime in Database,

Am I doing something wrong? Please help me or suggest the correct way,

Thanks

[image]